# Como ler the um ficheiro .csv e escrever numa lista?

Tags: java

Estou me iniciando em Java e estou com dificuldades em ler de um ficheiro e publicar numa lista. A lista é de tipo pré definido.

`List<Atleta> listaAtletas = new ArrayList<>();`

A classe `Atleta` não apresenta problemas e tem o seguinte código, juntamente com get e set para as variáveis `nome`, `idadeGrupo`, `tempo`.

```
public class Atleta
{
   private static int proximoNumero = 1; //numera automaticamente o numero de atletas criados 

   public int numero;       // numero do atleta
   public String nome;      // nome do atleta
   public String idadeGrupo;  // media, junior ou senior
   public int tempo;         // tempo demurado pelo atleta na maratona

   /**
    * Constructor para os objectos da class Atleta.
    */
   public Atleta() {
      super();
      this.nome = "";
      this.idadeGrupo = "media";
      this.tempo = 0;
      this.numero = this.proximoNumero;
      this.proximoNumero++;

    }
```

Na classe `MaratonaAdmin` é que não consigo ler do arquive e publicar na lista.
Não sei o que é que estou a fazer de errado nesta classe.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 * Class MaratonaAdmin - administra a maratona
 */
public class MaratonaAdmin
{

   private Atleta osAtletas;

   /**
    * Constructor para os objectos da class MaratonaAdmin
    */
   public MaratonaAdmin() {
      List<Atleta> listaAtletas = new ArrayList<>();
      // Para debug
      int tamanho = listaAtletas.size();  
      System.out.println("Tamanho da lista " + tamanho);
   }

   /**
    * Metodo que lê de arquive .CSV
    * Não tem argumento
    * Não retorna valores
    */
   public void lerOsAtletas() {
      FileReader arq = new FileReader("test.csv");
      String nome;
      String idadeGrupo;
      int tempo;
      Scanner linhaScanner;
      String linhaCurrente;
      Scanner bufferedScanner = null;
      bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.csv")));
      try {
         while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            linhaCurrente = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
            linhaScanner = new Scanner(linhaCurrente);
            linhaScanner.useDelimiter(",");
            nome = linhaScanner.next();
            idadeGrupo = linhaScanner.next();
            tempo = linhaScanner.next();
            listaAtletas.add(new Account(accountHolder, accountNumber, accountBalance));
         }
      }
      catch (Exception anException) {
         System.out.println("Erro: " + anException);
      }
      finally {
         try {
            bufferedScanner.close();
         }
         catch (Exception anException) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nesta parte:

```
listaAtletas.add(new Account(accountHolder, accountNumber, accountBalance));
```

> Você parece adicionar uma `Account` e não um `Atleta`.

*Acho* que aí está uma boa parte do erro. Fora isso, eu não entendi como você está criando um **atleta** novo, e adicionando na lista (está faltando código?)

De qualquer modo, alterei o seu código (bastante, desculpa!) para fazer uns testes, e acredito que você possa usar esse código para consertar o seu:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MaratonaAdmin {

    static List<Atleta> listaAtletas;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        listaAtletas = new ArrayList<>();
        lerOsAtletas();

        System.out.println("Tamanho da lista " + listaAtletas.size());

        for (Atleta atl : listaAtletas) {
            System.out.println("Atleta no.: " + atl.numero);
            System.out.println("Nome: " + atl.nome);
            System.out.println("Grupo: " + atl.idadeGrupo);
            System.out.println("Tempo: " + atl.tempo);
            System.out.println("#######");
        }
    }

    public static void lerOsAtletas() throws FileNotFoundException {

        FileReader arq = new FileReader("C://Users//danie//Documents//test.csv");

        Scanner bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(arq));
        try {
            while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String linhaCurrente = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
                Scanner linhaScanner = new Scanner(linhaCurrente);
                linhaScanner.useDelimiter(",");
                listaAtletas.add(new Atleta(linhaScanner.next(),
                  linhaScanner.next(), linhaScanner.next()));
                linhaScanner.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception anException) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + anException);
        } finally {
            try {
                bufferedScanner.close();
            } catch (Exception anException) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Tive que alterar a classe `Atleta` também (por motivo explicado anteriormente):

```
public class Atleta {
    private static int proximoNumero = 1;   
    public int numero;
    public String nome;
    public String idadeGrupo;
    public String tempo;

    public Atleta(String nome, String idadeGrupo, String tempo) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idadeGrupo = idadeGrupo;
        this.tempo = tempo;
        this.numero = Atleta.proximoNumero;
        Atleta.proximoNumero++;
    }
}
```

Além disso, o seu `int tempo;` não deve funcionar, pois o programa lê `String` do `.csv`, não é? A conversão terá que ser feita em outro momento (eu não incluí a conversão para simplificar o código).

> .csv usado para teste:

```
stackoverflow,junior,2:02:57
Torre Eiffel,senior,3:14:41
Empire State,media,4:21:18
```

> Resultado:

```
Tamanho da lista 3
Atleta no.: 1
Nome: stackoverflow
Grupo: junior
Tempo: 2:02:57
#######
Atleta no.: 2
Nome: Torre Eiffel
Grupo: senior
Tempo: 3:14:41
#######
Atleta no.: 3
Nome: Empire State
Grupo: media
Tempo: 4:21:18
#######
```

Answer (score 0):

A sua versão não funcionou mas ajudou me a encontrar o erro que tinha no codigo.
Obrigado pela ajuda e aqui fica o codigo completo.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Class MaratonaAdmin - administra a maratona
 */
public class MaratonaAdmin
{

   //private Atleta osAtletas;
   static List<Atleta> listaAtletas;

   /**
    * Constructor para os objectos da class MaratonaAdmin
    */
   public MaratonaAdmin() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      listaAtletas = new ArrayList<>();
      lerOsAtletas(); 
      for (Atleta atl : listaAtletas) {
          System.out.println("Atleta no.: " + atl.numero);
          System.out.println("Nome: " + atl.nome);
          System.out.println("Grupo: " + atl.idadeGrupo);
          System.out.println("Tempo: " + atl.tempo);
          System.out.println("#######");
        }

   }

   /**
    * Metodo que lê de arquive .CSV
    * Não tem argumento
    * Não retorna valores
    */
   public static void lerOsAtletas() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
        Scanner bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://Users//danie//Documents//test.csv")));
        try {
            while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String linhaCurrente = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
                Scanner linhaScanner = new Scanner(linhaCurrente);
                linhaScanner.useDelimiter(",");
                listaAtletas.add(new Atleta(linhaScanner.next(),
                  linhaScanner.next(), linhaScanner.next()));
                linhaScanner.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception anException) {
            System.out.println("Erro: " + anException);
        } finally {
            try {
                bufferedScanner.close();
            } catch (Exception anException) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Por que meu código não funcionou? Deu algum erro? (Importante saber para eu editar a resposta) - se minha resposta lhe ajudou, por favor clique no botão de 'aceitar' ao lado dela.

Comment: O resultado que eu colei é o próprio _output_ do programa - eu sei que isso não costuma ser desculpa, mas, _"na minha máquina ele roda"_... :p